# Why is an elliptic curve with $j$-invariant in $K$ defined over $K$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, projective-varieties

I often see in the literature some arguments like this:

"to show that an elliptic curve $E$ is defined over $\mathbb{F}_p$,
we show that the $j$-invariant of the curve is in $\mathbb{F}_p$."

But I thought in general there are elliptic curves not define over $\mathbb{F}_p$, which still have $j$-invariant $\mathbb{F}_p$?

What do they mean by "defined over" when they make a such implication?

1. $E$ is really defined over $\mathbb{F}_p$, i.e., the weierstrass equation of $E$ has coefficients in $\mathbb{F}_p$.
2. $E$ is not defined over $\mathbb{F}_p$, but it is isomorphic to a curve defined over $\mathbb{F}_p$.

Is it the case that "$E$ is defined over $K$ if and only if $j\in K$" when $K$ is a finite field?
I'm sure this is not true when the characteristic of $K$ is $0$, but I haven't thought about explicitly constructing an elliptic curve not defined over $\mathbb{F}_q$ but $j \in \mathbb{F}_q$, $q =p^r$.

Comment: What about $E/\Bbb{F}_7:y^2=x^3+i x$, $j(E)\in \Bbb{F}_7$? In characteristic not $2,3$ any elliptic curve $E/K$ is isomorphic over $K$ to some $y^2=x^3+ax+b$ and any (algebraic group) isomorphism to another curve is of the form $(x,y)\to (c^2 x,c^3 y)$ so it is easy to understand the whole family, the isomorphisms connecting them, and over what fields each curve and map is defined (that is all the twists of $E$).

Answer (score 3):

The meaning is: $E$ is defined over $\bar K$ and is isomorphic (over $\bar K$) to an elliptic curve defined over $K$.

$E$ with this property will certainly have $j\in K$. For the opposite direction (the one that you're interested in), if $\operatorname{char}K\neq2,3$ and $j\neq0,1728$ then
$$y^2=x^3+\frac{3j}{1728-j}\,x+\frac{2j}{1728-j}$$
has $j$-invariant $j$ and coefficients in $K$ (and $y^3=x^3+1$ and $y^3=x^3+x$ have $j=0$ and $j=1728$). In characteristic $2$ and $3$ one needs to do more work.

All of this is taken from Washington's book Elliptic curves.

Comment: yeah I know this from Silverman's book. If $K$ is a finite field, there are exactly two $K$-isomorphism classes of elliptic curves over $\overline{K}$ with the same $j$-invariant, and both classes can be represented by curves over $K$. I'm really asking if there are curves in the isomorphism classes (either over $K$ or $\overline{K}$) that are not defined over $K$ when $K$ is a finite field. For example, I can try to construct a curve $E:y^2=x^3+Ax+B$ with $A, B\in \mathbb{F}_{p^2}\setminus \mathbb{F}_p$ and $j(E) \in \mathbb{F}_p$ to check that.

Comment: hmm, for a given $j\in K$ you can take $A$ from some nontrivial extension of $K$, then compute $B$ (in possibly a bigger extension) so that you get your $j$. Not sure whether this is what you want.

Comment: Alright I found one using Sagemath. Write $\mathbb{F}_{7^2} = \mathbb{F}_{7}(\alpha)$, where $\alpha^2+6\alpha+3$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_{7}$. Then 
$E: y^2=x^3+(\alpha+4)x+(5\alpha+4)$ has $j$-invariant $1 \in \mathbb{F}_{7}$.